# Space character at the end of a string when saving to the database

Tags: c#, linq, sqldatatypes

I have a `nvarchar(50)` field in my table. When I save a string with `12 character Length` for example, it saves the string with `50 character length`. Actually it adds a space character at the end of the string. Should I select another data type?

```
tmp_Person.NameFamily = txt_NameFamily.Text.Trim();
PersonKBBSHDataContext.PersonInfos.InsertOnSubmit(tmp_Person);
PersonKBBSHDataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

When I save a string directly (in [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server)) in the `NameFamily` field of the table, everything is fine.

Comment: Cant you just use .Trim() on the text box value before you assign it to the name?

Comment: Something else must be wrong here. If you have a 12 chr string and you save it to an nvarchar(50), the database should not be adding padding with spaces at the end. Double check that you're really saving to nvarchar(50) column.

Comment: `tmp_Person.NameFamily` is `string (System.String)` in `.dbml` and problem is after i sending string for save in database. I'm saving to nvarchar(50) column.

Comment: error comes from `.dbml' file, with re add table to `dbml` everything goes fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I just added my table again in the `.dbml` file and everything went fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. Remove .IsFixedLength() from Nvarchar properties in Mapping class and my problem solved.

```
Me.Property(Function(t) t.Description).IsFixedLength().HasMaxLength(500)
```

Replaced with

```
Me.Property(Function(t) t.Description).HasMaxLength(500)
```

Comment: Had the same problem. Had to fix it in the `.edmx` file setting `FixedLength` attribute to `false` for the property in the relevant EntityType. The problem occurred because the column was set to `nchar` first.

Answer (score 1):

If using the Entity Framework, set the `Fixed Length` property to `true` on your NVarchar fields.

You can still use the `Trim` however that is just to 'fix' the `textBox.Text` value and has nothing to do with the database.

Answer (score -2):

Use this `Trim(txt_NameFamily.Text)`